# Download charts in flexdashboard

Tags: shiny, flexdashboard

I am trying to use a download button in the input column of a flex dashboard to download a collection of charts rendered as *.pdf. The entire dashboard works just fine, and the download button renders properly; however, when I click the download button, the file that does get downloaded does not contain the intended charts. The warning I get from my Mac when it tries to open the file is that the file might be damaged or that it's a form that Preview (or Acrobat) doesn't recognize. The following is a highly redacted form of my code that contains the problematic sections. Any guidance on how to get charts to download in a flexdashboard as charts download in Shiny?

````
---
title: "My Model"
runtime: shiny
output:
    flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
        theme: cerulean
        vertical_layout: scroll
    orientation: rows   
---

```{r global, include=FALSE}
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(flexdashboard)
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
library(knitr)
library(RColorBrewer)
source("MLHS_Distributions.R")
source("interp.R")
source("tooltips.R")
```

```{r Inputs}
downloadButton("downlaodReport","Price Comparision Report")

downloadHandler(filename = function() {
     filename = paste0("ModelReport-", Sys.Date(), ".pdf")
   },
     content = function(file) {
         pdf(file, width = 8.5, height = 6.14)
         renderPrint({output$gg.prob.win.price()})
         dev.off()
   }
)
```

```{r priceProbWinChart}
renderPlot({
gg.prob.win.price <- --ggplot code--

plot(gg.prob.win.price)
})
```
````

Comment: YOu can use `ggsave` to save ggplots

Comment: Does this work in flexdashboard? I don't seem to be able to find any documentation for how to implement that.